# Probability of sitting at chairs?

Tags: probability

Here is a question I have been toying with a good time now. The question is: You, 7 boys, and 4 girls are randomly seated in 12 chairs arranged in a line. What is the probability that there is at least one girl sitting next to you?

I tried to solve this question using complementary probability, and finding the probability that only boys sit next to you, then subtracting it from 1. I got a final answer of $\frac{19}{33}$, but that seems counterintuitive, since there are LESS girls than boys. I am not sure if this is correct, or if this is a correct approach. Can someone please help?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could approach a few different ways, but the easiest approach in my opinion is indeed the one you used of trying to find the probability that only boys sit next to you.

Something which I expect trip many people up in their calculations for this or similar problems is the possibility that you sit on the end of the line where you have only one person sitting next to you, not two.

The probability that you sit on the end of the line is $\frac{2}{12}$.  Given that this has occurred, the probability that the only adjacent seat next to you is occupied by a boy is $\frac{7}{11}$.

The probability that you sit somewhere in the middle is $\frac{10}{12}$.  Given that this has occurred, the probability that the seat to your left is occupied by a boy is $\frac{7}{11}$.  Given that this has also occurred, the probability that the seat to your right is also occupied by a boy is $\frac{6}{10}$.

This gives the probability of sitting next to only boys as being:

$$\frac{2}{12}\times \frac{7}{11} + \frac{10}{12}\times \frac{7}{11}\times \frac{6}{10} = \frac{14}{33}$$

This leads to the probability of having at least one girl sitting next to you as:

$$1 - \frac{14}{33}=\frac{19}{33}\approx 0.58$$

which you correctly found.

This answer should not be alltogether surprising however.  Consider a somewhat related problem of flipping a fair coin twice and asking what the probability that you flipped at least one head.  The answer to that question would be $0.75$, and our answer here is significantly less than that.

Indeed, if we were to repeat the question and find the probability of sitting next to at least one *boy*, you'd get an answer of $\frac{28}{33}$, which as you would have guessed is a higher probability than what we found earlier since there are more boys than girls.  What you seem to be forgetting is that these two events are not mutually exclusive.  It is possible to sit next both a girl *and* a boy simultaneously, and so we shouldn't really be comparing to $0.5$ as a baseline to see if the probability makes sense.